# Output clob variable to file using Spool

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am connected to an Oracle database on a remote server in SQL Developer. I have a PL/SQL script that stores data in clob variable. I wish to output this variable's data to a file ***on my local machine***.

I came across `SPOOL`, but I guess I am not using it correctly.

Here is what my script looks like:

```
set echo off
set serveroutput on FORMAT WRAPPED
set verify off
set feedback off
set termout off

DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);

SPOOL C:\home\output.txt

declare
    content CLOB;
begin
    -- do something with content
end;

spool off

set termout on
set feedback on
```

When I run the script, nothing gets written to the file C:\home\output.txt. I wish the data in the clob variable `content` to be written to the file.

How should I proceed?

Edit: If someone knows a better/another way of writing a clob variable to a file (besides SPOOL), please feel free to suggest.

Edit 2: Maybe its worth mentioning that my clob variable has content greater than 32767 bytes. I don't know how this would affect the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try such a SET set?

```
set linesize 32767 
set long 32767 
set longchunksize 32767 
set trimout on 
set trimspool on

spool output.txt

select clob_column
from your_table;

spool off
```

As CLOB is longer than 32767, it won't fit into a single line.